# Obtaining video duration

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api

A search is made to obtain videos. How do I obtain the duration of the video?

```
            for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
            if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
                VideoID.append(search_result["id"]["videoId"])
                ChannelID.append(search_result["snippet"]["channelId"])
                VideoName.append(search_result["snippet"]["title"])
                ChannelName.append(search_result["snippet"]["channelTitle"])
                videoDuration.append(search_result["contentDetails"]["duration"])
```

The last line returns a key error. Judging by the API on the website this is how it should be done but the documentation is pretty weird to be honest.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Cheers

Comment: Can you print your `contentDetails` dictionary to verify that a `duration` key-value pair is being returned from your API call?  Are you sure you're passing in `contentDetails` for `part in your `Videos.list` method?  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [search.list endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) does not accept/provide contentDetails. You will need to take the id results from search and make another call to the [videos.list endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) for that.